# Why this generic reference can't point to this similar extended class in Java?

Tags: java, generics

Why this generic reference can't point to this similar extended class in Java?

http://goo.gl/evqOcP

```
public class HelloWorld{

    public static void main(String []args){

        Interface<Integer,Object> test = new Test();

        System.out.println(test.method(test));
    }
}


public interface Interface<A, B extends Object> {
    public A method(B param);
}

public class Test implements Interface<Integer,Test> {
    private int a = 0;

    public Integer method(Test param){
        return param.a;
    }
}
```

I get this error when compiling

```
HelloWorld.java:5: error: incompatible types                                                                                                                         
        Interface<Integer,Object> test = new Test();                                                                                                                 
                                         ^                                                                                                                           
  required: Interface<Integer,Object>                                                                                                                                
  found:    Test                                                                                                                                                     
1 error
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The class `Test` implements `Interface<Integer,Test>` and the type is declared as `Interface<Integer,Object>`. This assignment is not allowed because Generics are `invariant`:

`Interface<Integer,Test>` is neither a subtype nor a supertype of `Interface<Integer,Object>`. So, `Interface<Integer,Test>` cannot be assigned to `Interface<Integer,Object>`.

You can change the assignment statement as below to make it work :

`Interface<Integer, ? extends Test> test = new Test();`

Answer (score 4):

Your `Test` class implements `Interface<Integer,Test>`, but you are declaring it as of type `Interface<Integer, Object>`, hence the type mismatch.

You can change the reference/assignment to:

```
Interface<Integer, Test> test = new Test();
```

Also note that you will not be able to invoke `method(test)` on `test`, since the method takes a `Test` argument and not an `Interface<...>` argument.

Comment: @pdem what edit are you referring to? I'm still seeing the *incompatible types*...

Comment: Ok i Thought that the declaration of interface has changed because "extends Object" has no interest in the line "public interface Interface<A, B extends Object> {"

Comment: thanks. I see it at 99%. What I am trying to do is using a more "general" interface to point to distinct Interfaces changing B in the object and using the same array of type Interface<Integer,Object>...

Answer (score 1):

Think of it like this, suppose `class Animal`and `class Dog extends Animal`, `class Elephant extends Animal`.

Now you have a kennel in which you can fit Dogs, `List<Dog> kennel` and also 
 you have a zoo : `List<Animal> zoo`.

Is kennel a kind of zoo ? No, you cannot `add` Elephants to the kennel.

Is zoo a kind of kennel ? No, you cannot ensure it only returns Dog when you `get` from it.

So as mentionned in other answers, there is no subtype relationship between the two generic containers, hence the assignment fails.